# Fluent Validation, how to unit test rule that is using custom property validator

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, fluentvalidation

I am using a custom property validator (UniqueValueValidator) to validate some properties:

```
RuleFor(e => e.Name)
     .SetValidator(new UniqueValueValidator<PersonInput, Person, string>(_repository.Queryable()))
     .WithMessage("Duplicate name");
```

My unit test looks as follows.

```
public void ShouldNotHaveValidationError_WhenNameIsUnique()
    {
       var people = DataFaker.People.AsQueryable().BuildMock().Object; // mocking IQueryable as it is passed to unique validator's constructor.

       _peopleRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Queryable()).Returns(people);

       // Person named "Al" exists in my DataFaker.People collection.
       var model = new PersonInputModel{ Name = "Al" };

       var result = _validator.TestValidate(model); // `result` array is always empty

       result.ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor(person => person.Name);
     }
```

Results array is always empty, even though It should fail, as "Al" is a duplicate name, do I have to somehow mock UniqueValueValidator as well, I could not find any examples in the official documentation.